# Middleware in MVC structure with expressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model-view-controller, middleware

I am creating an MVC structured app. For me this is a new concept. I am having trouble as where to place my middleware. Here's how my app is structured:

Server:

```
//routes
app.use('/' , userRoutes);
```

User routes :

```
//controllers
const postUser = userController.postUser;
const getUser = userController.getUser;

//route
router.route('/user').post(postUser).get(getUser);
```

And my controllers :

```
const {check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

const postUser = (req,res) => {
    res.send(req.body);
    console.log('POSTED')
};

const getUser = (req,res) => {
    res.send(req.body );
    console.log('GOTTEM');
};

module.exports = {postUser , getUser};
```

Where in this bunch should i implement my middleware. I want to use express-validator to check for fields etc, so it has to sit in between the requested path and the callback. Im a bit confused as to where to add my middleware.

Answer (score 0):

It's My Suggestion to use [express Boiler Plate](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) for Better MVC Directory Structure and better Routes Understanding.

Answer (score 0):

So after trying some things out myself i've figured it out.

In my routers where i chain all the methods to a specific route:

```
router.route('/user').post(middleware,postUser).get(getUser);
```

This worked for me.